# How to run reindex without SSH access?

Tags: magento2, cron, reindex, ssh

I install **Magento 2**. All is good. When I arrive on the **admin page**, I have the reindex problem. I try to read many tutorial to correct this problem but, or I can't because I haven't SSH on my server, or I can't understand (and every tutorials are in english). I see tutorial with linux command, but I have windows. Somebody to explain me, point per point ?

Comment: Welcome to Magento StackExchange! @user57741, you get more opportunities to get an answer to your question if you ask your question in English.

Comment: Bonjour, pouvez-vous expliquer votre problème en anglais s'il vous plait?

Comment: Ok I try : I install Magento 2. All is good. When I arrive on the admin page, I have the reindex problem. I try to read many tutorial to correct this problem but, or I can't because I haven't SSH on my server, or I can't understand (and every tutorials are in english). I see tutorial with linux command, but I have windows. 

Somebody to explain me, point per point ? 

Sorry for my bad english !Thx !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after translate your question I come to know that

You can not connect SSH as you are using windows.

you can use putty to connect ssh

below the tutorial can help you to connect SSH

https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404604/using-ssh-in-putty-

after connecting `SSH`

go to your magento root via below command

```
cd /yourMagentoDirectory
```

Then fire below command depend on which magento you are using

`Magento 1.x`

```
php shell/indexer.php reindex
```

for `Magento2.x`

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: Ok it is good. I upgrade mys erver OVh to "pro". Now I have SSh...; (but more expansive :()

Comment: If my answer help you then mark as accepted so other user who has same problem can take benefit